# Disable ClickEvent on a Composite?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have implemented a button in GWT which is Composite and want to implement the HasEnabled interface to enable/disable the click event on this button. This is what I did:

```
public class MyButton extends Composite implements HasText HasClickHandlers, HasEnabled {

FocusPanel panel;
boolean enabled;

public MyButton() {
        panel = new FocusPanel();
        label = new Label("Test");
        panel.add(label);
        initWidget(panel);
}




@Override
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
    return panel.addClickHandler(handler);
}


@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}


@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;

}


}
```

**How do I have to disable the ClickHandler on the panel when enabled is set to false?**

Answer (score 0):

```
HandlerRegistration handlerRegistration = panel.addClickHandler(handler);
```

When you want to disable it:

```
if (handlerRegistration != null) {
    handlerRegistration.removeHander();
}
```

Comment: But, when I want to enable the click handler later without setting it up again?

Comment: Add it back! panel.addClickHandler(handler);

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write a wrapper click handler, which executes the "real" click handler only when the component is enabled:

```
@Override
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(final ClickHandler handler) {
    return panel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            if(enabled){
                handler.onClick(event);
            }
        }
    });
}
```